# mapFrag.getMapAsync() problems in a while loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I really need help for a problem I don´t know how to solve.
I´m trying to make an application for my father, and I will work with Map.
The problem is specific in a `mapFrag.getMapAsync()` inside a while loop.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while ( mapFrag.getMapAsync() == null){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    configMap();
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

`while ( mapFrag.getMapAsync()`, this line gets an error that says'

```
getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) in SupportMapFragment cannot be applied to ()
```

The OnMapReadyCallback was implemented on a MainActivity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Map:onMapReadyCallback can not be applied to this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340848/google-maponmapreadycallback-can-not-be-applied-to-this-activity)

Comment: unfortunately nope, my problem is focused in a while with getMapAsync as a parameter

Comment: In that case, can you provide a link to the documentation for the _exact_ version of `getMapAsync()` you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

According documentation for [`MapFragment.getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)):

> `public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)`
>
> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap
>   instance is ready to be used.
>
> Note that:
>
> This method must be called from the main thread.
>
> The callback will be executed in the main thread.
>
> In the case where Google Play services is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be triggered until the user
>   installs it.
>     In the rare case where the `GoogleMap` is destroyed immediately after creation, the callback is not triggered.
>
> The `GoogleMap` object provided by the callback is non-null.

Especially this:

> Parameters `callback`     The callback object that will be triggered when
>   the map is ready to be used.

In your call `mapFrag.getMapAsync()` there is no `OnMapReadyCallback` parameter. So, you should add it:

```
...
mapFrag.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
})
...
```

And you shouldn't call `getMapAsync()` in separate thread, because of (see above link to documentation):

- This method must be called from the main thread.
- The callback will be executed in the main thread.

So, please read carefully official [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) page.